# how to make list navigation in material ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want navigation like https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/ and same ul > li > a> sapn structure like material ui website made in his side navigation. and I want the same effect also.

I used a lot of tricks but it restults fail. Please help

here is my code

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <List>
            {[0, 1, 2, 3].map(value => (
                <ListItem key={value}  className={classes.listItem}>
                    <Link button to="/about">
                        <ListItemText primary={`Line item ${value + 1}`} />
                    </Link>
                </ListItem>
            ))}
        </List>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Colin I have updated the question

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: i didnt get any error but i am unable to get same structure as material ui site has in its sidenav  ul > li > a > span and the effect on anchor like a button

Comment: so I want a peace of code of material ui can i can get same structure and effect which is in material ui site's side navigation. I've tried a lot but unable to get the structure and effect